# Keeping result of MySQL function (that gets used in WHERE) in my query results

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have got a MySQL function on my database, that calculates the levenshtein distance between two strings. 
`levenstein("str1","str2"), returns INT`

I have a table filled with strings, and I would like my query to return the most relevant rows to the input string, if any. My Query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE levenshtein('John',name) <= 15
ORDER BY date DESC`
```

As you see, the levenshtein distance gets used in the `WHERE` clause. The function itself works just fine.

But in my result, I would also like to have a column with the specific levenshtein distance of each row from `"John"`.
It gets calculated in the `WHERE` clause, how can I change my query to actually store it and have it come out with the rest of the results?

Comment: `SELECT *, levenshtein('John',name) as dist from...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery, and filter the result of that:

```
SELECT name, score FROM (
  SELECT name, levenshtein('John', name) AS score, date
  FROM my_table
) AS t
WHERE t.score <= 15
ORDER BY date DESC
```

This gives you the result of the function as a plain column in the outer query, so you can filter, sort, etc by it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function in your list of fields

```
SELECT *,levenshtein('John',name) as lev FROM my_table
HAVING lev <= 15
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Here is the SQLFiddle that illustrates the concept: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6274e2/2

Comment: In SQL Server a *deterministic* function would lead to one evaluation; I don't know about MySQL and/or how it differentiates between deterministic and non-deterministic expressions. (A reference to the appropriate MySQL optimization documentation would be nice.)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the calculation in your selection, name it, and reference it in a having clause:

```
SELECT
  *, levenshtein('John',name) as lev
FROM my_table
HAVING
  lev <= 15
ORDER BY
  date DESC;
```

Comment: `From, where, group, having, select, order`. Alias in select only available in order clause...

Comment: Really? Just tried it and I have no problem using an alias in my having clause on my system...

Comment: Actually mysql allows that but it can be turned off and is not standard.

Comment: Not recommended: MySQL: "works"; SQL Server: syntax error (requires GROUP BY); Oracle: different result (entire result considered single group)